# Is there any possible way to lock query navigation pane (access)?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I made a database with access, and I created dataentryform and inside it there are some subforms (I have related tables), I used query to provive these subform and without these qaueries I cannot enter data into subforms (if I delete these queries then when I open main form I see blank rectangular inside myform instead of them. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOTFd.jpg)Is there any possible way to lock query and also subform in navigation pane?

Comment: Your question is quite vague and unclear. Can you provide a [mcve] hat demonstrates your problem?

Comment: That's a photo, not a [mcve].

Comment: question is : I have some queries and they are visible in navigation pane , user can delet them by mistake and I dont want user have this ability. I can hide them then user dont see them in navigatioin pane so not able to delete them .I am asking is there anyother way to prevent user be able to change or delete this query? can I lock these queries? as I said I can hide those queries from user vision.

Comment: Ah, I see, I understand your question now. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, as long as the user is running an application on his own PC, you cannot prevent him from deliberately modifying/breaking it. This is true for all applications, not only MS-Access-based ones.

That said, there are some ways to make it harder to accidentally modify it:

1. The recommended way is to start Access in "runtime mode", either by specifying the `/runtime` flag on the command line or by renaming your `accdb`/`accde` to `accdr`. That way, the user won't *have* a navigation pane and can only interact with the application through the ways that you, as the developer, explicitly provide.
2. You can use [user-level security](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/101982/5273) to "lock" your queries. However, user-level security was deprecated with Access 2007. It can only be used with the old, legacy `mdb` format (rather than the new `accdb` format) and should not be used for new projects.